# Which is the prime holy book of Hindus?

Tags: vedas, bhagavad-gita, gita

Everyone says that the prime holy book of Hindus is *Vedas* but if it is true then why Hindus take oath on Gita, and why not on Vedas?

Is there any other reason for taking oaths on Gita? or Veda is not the prime holy book?

Answer (score 6):

Vedas are an entire library while Gita is a single book which gives a summary of the Vedic teachings. It is more convenient to use a single book rather than a whole library.
Moreover it also helps that Gita is one of the Prasthana-trayas of the popular Vedanta school.

Comment: @pradip : you can't say Gita is not a single book, Gita is something that may enable to write even Vedas, You shall not underestimate Gita this way. Gita can let you achieve everything.

Comment: @logical Hindu: I said that Gita is a single book. I don't understand why you are saying that I said Gita is not a single book.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Sorry Please read this You can't say this, Gita is not a Single book(You said : Geeta is single book.), I am saying Geeta is every thing.

Comment: @LogicalHindu : you just cannot rewrite the vedas after reading Geeta